# Removing the gaps when extruding lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, extrude

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2

I was wondering if there is a way to fill the gaps that appear when extruding line shapefiles?

My shapefile lies on top of a DEM:
[image]

When using the extrusion option "using it as a value that features are extruded to" (which is the only one that works), I get this result:

[image]

The result is superb, but I really would like to close the gaps somehow. Is there any method of doing this?